# Ms Access table or Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a very interesting question.

Let's say I have a table in MS Access which has the following 7 columns:

```
studentID, firstName, lastName, courseName, homework, grade, semester
```

The table takes 3 homework per semester and calculate the average of those homework for each student.

Now I want to have another table/query that will have the same heading as the first table with an id pointing to the average (the average only) of the 3 homework for each student. But when you click on the id field of the second table it will open the first table with the details of the 3 homework for each student.

I hope you understand my question. I have finished the first table, but I don't know how to go about the second table/query.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever process you use to post new records in your first table would need to also recalculate the new average and post/update that student's record in the second table.  Doing that would keep the information in the second table up to date.

As far as the clicking part, I'll only make a broad suggestion based on where I think you are in your programming experience and what kind of project you're likely working on: You'd likely create a form (a screen) that displays the information from the second table.  You would use an Event of that table (like maybe the "On Dbl Click" Event) to trigger the display of the appropriate records from the first table on another Form.  Some VBA code would be required, but you have to get the structure first - how do you want to display the information?  What kind of interface do you want to provide for the operator?  etc.

EDIT1: After your additional description, I'll stand by my original thought that at the point when a record is added to the first table (the detail table), you'd use VBA code (we're not far enough along in your description for me to be any more specific than that) to also do the average calculation and update the second table.  You'd then write a report on the second table.  The reports aren't interactive, so there will be no clicking on the report to open forms (as far as I know), but you could do this with a form -- if you wanted to approach it that way instead of using a report.

EDIT2:

I'd suggest a structure more like this.  Note the additional "Students" table.  One could easily argue for a "Courses" table, but I'll skip that for this exercise.

```
table Students:
studentID - Short Text
firstName - Short Text
lastName - Short Text

table Homework:
studentID - Short Text
courseName - Short Text
homework - Short Text
grade - Number
semester - Short Text

table Averages:
studentID - Short Text
courseName - Short Text
avg - Number
semester - Short Text
```

In your form where you allow editing of the Homework table, you'd use an Event that makes sense (one that will be triggered each time data is changed -- will depend on what control you use to present your data to the operator).  This Event would need to trigger VBA code where you'd recalculate the updated student's average and then update the Averages table.  If you do this the Averages table will always be up to date.  You'd then need to write your report(s).

As for on-screen "drill down" into the details, you'd take a form where you display the Averages table to the operator and write some VBA code in an Event (like maybe "On Double Click).  This VBA code would need to detect which record was selected, then open a form that displays the Homework table and filters only for the selected student.

In all of the above, you'd likely use queries instead of tables -- so that you could include the Student information (last name, first name).

Comment: I want to display the records in an access report. I would like to consider myself as an intermediate access programmer. You can suggest whatever you have in mind I will be able to follow you.

Comment: Let me give you an example for you to better understand

Comment: This will be table1
001 Jane Doe Chemistry homework1 89 fall
001 Jane Doe Chemistry homework2 95 fall
001 Jane Doe Chemistry homework3 98 fall
Then a txt box with the Avg=94

Comment: then This will be table 2
someIDNum Jane Doe Homework chemistry 94 fall
So when you click on someIDNum it will open the details which is in table1 in a report/form

Comment: To summary it, I want to be able to STORE the avg of the three homework in table2 wih a link to the details of the scores in table1

Comment: Thanks @CraigD for your effort.While there might be many ways to solve a problem in Access,  I used a query to get the job done and I did not need to create any additional table. Once again thank you, your first answer was a source of inspiration as it sparked some ideas in my mind to help me resolve the problem.Thank you

Comment: Glad my efforts sparked your creativity!  If you feel like doing so, please up vote my post or mark it as an answer.